# CreateJS CDN performance problems

Tags: performance, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

Checking performance page via Lighthouse in Chrome DevTools and PageSpeedInsights see that the https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js is causing in my page an specific problem because is causing a big blocking time in main thread.
Is there any tip or advice to optimize that script for load performance? Thanks

For example:

[image]

Comment: Run a performance trace in developer tools and see what is blocking the main thread. The script iself won't be blocking the thread for that long it will be how you are using it. Are you using it to create loads of elements? If so try simplifying them or creating them on page scroll etc. At the moment that is all the info we can give as it is your use of the library causing the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is because of Ads where they are in and its weight a lot in this file. Is there any advise to optimize Ads too heavy? thanks